# Read data from latest index generated by ILM policy rollover

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-template, ilm

I have both `Elasticsearch` and `Logstash` in version `7.9.1-1` installed. Here's the policy I've created:

**PUT _ilm/policy/test-policy**

```
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_age": "2d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And its corresponding template:

**PUT _template/test-template**

```
{
  "index_patterns": ["test-*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.lifecycle.name": "test-policy",
    "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "test-read_n_write"
  }
}
```

And, finally, the initial alias:

**PUT test-000001**

```
{
  "aliases": {
    "test-read_n_write":{
      "is_write_index": true
    }
  }
}
```

After the first rollover, I'd like to have the alias point to the newly generated index (i.e. `test-000002`) only for **both read and write** operations - instead of just writing to the most recent one and searching multiple indices with the `test-read_n_write` alias.

Am I able to do that with automatic rollover?

Comment: Do you still need the old index or you will never read from it anymore?

Comment: @Val I need it for searching through a secondary "general" alias, which in this case would search through all indices.

Comment: I don't understand why you have two different aliases, though... `sslvpntraffic-write` and `test-read_n_write` can you explain in more details what they do?

Comment: @Val My bad, missed editing that part out. Fixed it now.

Comment: Tough one, as the whole point of ILM is twofold: 1) enable writes into a the latest index + 2) enable reads from all historical indexes

Comment: @Val I see, so I'm assuming that would basically go against the design of ILM and so there's no way it could be achieved through conventional means?

Comment: You can achieve anything you desire, just maybe not with a single command. It's definitely possible to manage that yourself using the `_aliases` endpoint. You're completely free as to where you want your aliases to point to.

Comment: @Val Would you consider scheduling the alias update through a cronjob to be a bad workaround?

Comment: Not necessarily, since your rollover will happen every two days, you can schedule the alias update around the same time (but after the rollover)